# Sticky UINavigationbar after RefreshControl refreshed since iOS 11

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, ios11, uirefreshcontrol

[image: navbar stays big]

We have a modulised App using two Navigation-hierarchies, therefore the two stacked Navbars…
Sometimes, when pulling the refreshcontrol the navbar stays big and does not drop back to the normal size after finishing the refresh. I can only guess, in which case it drops back and in which it doesnt… Visual debugger shows, that the view using this space is a `_UINavigationBarLargeTitleView`. In `viewDidLoad`, the `self.navigationController.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles` is set to `NO`.

[image]

RefreshControl is added in `viewDidLoad` via:

```
self.refreshControl = [RefreshControl new];
```

Some things i already tried:

- setting the tableViews `contentOffset` to (0,-1).
- set prefersLargeTitles to `YES`, then to `NO`.
- set the UINavigationControllers self.navigationItem.`largeTitleDisplayMode = UINavigationItemLargeTitleDisplayModeNever;`

  - logging the different states of the UIRefreshControl: sticky view and working view produces the same logging.

Does anyone have an idea what could cause this problem? As i said, i am not even sure when exactly this happens and when not…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that this issue only happens when `navigationBar.isTranslucent == false`. I needed this setting to get a real 100% black navigation bar.

For the time being I use this extremely dirty hack, inspired by the answer of Exception:

```
self.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Definitely a bug from Apple. Could not make it work except for the workaround below.

```
tableView.reloadData {
    // Slightly scroll up, moving the navigation bar back to place
    self.tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: -0.3), animated: false)
}
```

NOTE: Must be after the tableView has reloaded and with no animation.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's a bug from Apple.
Try this

`tableView.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
//Because of a bug in iOS11 that leaves empty placeholder for refresh control
navigationController?.navigationBar.setNeedsLayout()
navigationController?.navigationBar.layoutIfNeeded()`

also try

`navigationController?.navigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = true`

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you have deformed title or first cell you can add this line:

```
tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), at: .top, animated: true)
```

It should help to return title or cell in the normal state. Fully code may be looking like this:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
   self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
   if self.refreshControl!.isRefreshing {
       self.refreshControl!.endRefreshing()
   }
   self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
   self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), at: .top, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the cause was the setting nil to my `tableView.tableFooterView` with `tableView.reloadData()`.
So I just started hiding `tableView.tableFooterView` instead of setting nil to that view and my glitch gone